# Backand social sign in issue

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, backand

I'm using ionic with backand and cordova,

Does anyone have faced backand( serverless development and deployment platform ) with sign in problem with github and google.

for github i am able to connect from app but after authentication its not get back to application while,

google its simply say "Load error"

it would great if anyone can assist me in this issue

Comment: Hi, thanks for using Backand! Have you tried in multiple browsers? What about in an incognito session? I've just checked several of my apps and don't have any problems with google authentication. I'm happy to help out, but will need more information!

Comment: Hey thanks @MattBillock
No, my concern with ionic cordova mobile app, i have not tried with browser as i need this in mobile application